# getting netfx3 error while installing sql server 2014?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm installing `sql server 2014` but everything goes fine but suddenly it says

> The following has occurred: Error while enabling windows feature:
>   Netfx3, error code: -2146498298, please try enabling.. bah blah..

Could you just please help, what to do? I'm trying to resolving this issue from `2 Weeks` but not being able to solve that. please Help!

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: please try enabling what, exactly? your listing of the error code isn't very helpful, but it seems like it's trying to tell you that it can't use .Net Framework 3 because you have disabled it on the machine somehow....

Comment: in fact, a 2 minute google search turned up http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting101.htm

Comment: No, Everything is enabled just fine.. recently i install windows 8 and then `.netFramework` and then `Visual studio`.. that's it .. now it's telling `.Net framework is not enabled`? ..please help :(

Comment: clearly the error is telling you that you did not enable .Net 3 / 3.5... you may have installed .Net 4 / 4.5 but that isn't what SQL is looking for.  try following the link I posted or the link that would have been in the error you didn't include here.

Comment: What if, if i download separately `.NET Framework 3.0/3.5`?..

Comment: no, .Net Framework 3.5 is already a feature in windows 8, you CANNOT install it from a download, you must enable the feature in the windows features, as both the article I linked and the official Microsoft documentation for the error tells you to do.

Comment: for more references, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your second link was very helpful ..thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Please install .NET 3.5 and you should be fine. Apparently .NET 3.5 is still needed for the installation (may be server too)